# What UI can I use in my C++ OpenGL project?

Tags: c++, user-interface, opengl, visual-studio-2013

I make a program using C++ and OpenGL to visualize Minkowski addition. I use Visual Studio 2013. I need to make some kind of user interface - user must be able to set number of vertices, give coordinates of each point etc.

Program actually has two separate windows - one for polygon displaying, second one is for UI.

What should I do? Should I use a library, or maybe can I make my own UI?

Comment: check out win32 tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Visual Studio, the simplest way would be to use MFC. It isn't awesome but it's quite easy to use, especially if your gui needs to be simple.

There should be an option somewhere near the "console application", during new project creation.